# How to find the cause of weird errors in my JavaScript program?

Tags: javascript

```
function wpnChs() {
  var p1 = prompt("Do you take a SWORD or a CLUB to battle?").toUpperCase();
  var HP = 1;
  var EHP = 1;
  var dmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1);
  var dmgT = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1);
  var first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1);
  if (p1 === "SWORD") {
    HP = 10;
    EHP = 9;
    dmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    dmgT = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  } else if (p1 === "CLUB") {
    HP = 11;
    EHP = 9;
    dmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    dmgT = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  } else {
    wpnChs();
  }
}

function dmgD1() {
  EHP -= dmg;
}

function dmgD2() {
  HP -= dmgT;
}

function fR() {
  if (p1 === "SWORD") {
    dmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    dmgT = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  } else {
    dmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    dmgT = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }
}

var fight = function() {
  if (first === 0 || 2) {
    dmgD1();
    if (dmg === 0) {
      alert("You attacked, but the enemy dodged it!");
      fR();
      fight();
    } else {
      alert("You attacked and did " + dmg + " damage. The enemy now has " + EHP
        +
        " health");
      if (EHP <= 0) {
        alert("You killed the enemy!")
      } else {
        fR();
        fight();
      }
    }
  } else {
    dmgD2();
    if (dmgT === 0) {
      alert("The enemy attacked, but you dodged it!");
      fR();
      fight();
    } else {
      alert("The enemy attacked and did " + dmgT + " damage. You now have " + HP
        +
        " health.");
      if (HP <= 0) {
        alert("You died!");
      } else {
        fR();
        fight();
      }
    }
  }
};

wpnChs();
fight();
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be a good idea to show what errors you are getting?

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript

Comment: What is the weird error?

Comment: Your first error `alert("You attacked and did " + dmg + " damage. The enemy now has " + EHP+" health");` you have no `+` to join the `EHP` with `"health");` you seem to have a line break between them for some reason. Many more errors, I suggest you learn how to use the browser console to find them.

Comment: @NewToJS There’s no error on those lines. That’s working code.

Comment: Several of your variables are out-of-scope. Please research about JavaScript’s function scope and where to declare variables.

Comment: Xufox, tell that to jsfiddle since I have just done a copy/paste of the source code... unless those errors where made while the OP attempted to share the source code in the question. I had submitted my comment before any changes to the question so if you look at the original post you'll find my comment is relevant and correct. I can only go by what the OP is giving.

Comment: @NewToJS This part works for me in JSFiddle as well. It also works in the browser console. I’m testing only the `alert` call with the numerous line-breaks, with some pre-defined values for `dmg` and `EHP`.

Comment: @Xufox are you testing it with the original source posted? Before any edits were made the the question? I don't think so. Like I said. I posted my comment before those changes where made so if you click edit and copy/paste the original source code you will find those exact errors. I understand the OP had made a mistake while trying to share the source code but I'm just pointing out at the time of that comment to the original post, it's correct.

Comment: @NewToJS Do you mean the very first revision of this question? Even the Markdown source works fine. The rendered output obviously can’t be used.

Comment: @Xufox A copy of the source in the **first** post https://jsfiddle.net/7r2vr0td/  Like I said, the OP had made a mistake while trying to share the source code but wasn't aware until someone else had edited the question. Need we continue with this?

Comment: @Xufox - I recommend against adding "please help me" into questions, especially in the title. It is routinely used as a form of begging, and can attract downvotes if people think it was written by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so the first problem is the issues with scoping. You're trying to use variables declared in the first function through out the code when they are scoped for only the first function. You could fix this problem a few different ways.

1. You could declare them outside of the functions making them more
   global.
2. You could still declare them inside the current function and pass
   them as parameters. Like fight(first, dmg); *I'd recommend this way.*

I found this initial error by using the Chrome developer tools - try pushing F-12 while you're browsing and trying to run your code, you'll often get a console error - like the one below if somethings not working. These console errors often provide invaluable insight into what's going on in your application.

[image: Error in the console]

Try reading this to learn more about how to use dev tools: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

I'd also recommend that you look here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp to learn more about scoping in javascript.

**Keep at it.** The first steps can be a bit confusing but once you get it figured out it starts to all come together.